# Is there a command to clone entities?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there any way to clone entities or at least summon a lot with one command block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `/summon` command you can make any amount of same entities you want. **There is no command that would take entity A and make entity A'.** You always need to create **new entity** in vanilla Minecraft.

However if you want to take entity A and re-summon it somewhere else, you can. All you need is to have the command what summoned that first entity and reuse it (for example via redstone clock). And if you want to reuse it on custom places (for example summon entity on 5 marks at time), you can with help of `/execute` command.

Wiki: [Execute](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#execute), [Summon](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#summon), [Scoreboard](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard#Command_reference), Summon generator examples : [1](http://www.minecraftupdates.com/summon-command) , [2](https://mcstacker.bimbimma.com/)

---

So, let's say you have 4 player party and you want to face them some equal mob challenge. This command will summon one mob for every player which will be targeted(for example everybody in "arena", so on some coordinates with some range):

```
/execute @a[x=100,y=64,z=100,r=30] ~5 ~0 ~0 /summon Spider ~0 ~1 ~0 {CustomName:Tough Spider,CustomNameVisible:1,Health:100.0f}
```

This command will summon one spider for every player, 5 blocks away from that player in X direction.

---

Another example:
You want to summon 4 zombies surrounding the player when he enters the centre of the room. Then you need (aside from commands checking when he enters the area  - or redstone):

- a) 4 same `execute+summon` commands, every one pointing to another coordinates
- b) prepared "marks" to execute one `execute+summon` command on them as we done before on players

Marks can be done by Scoreboards and some dummy entities. For this example you can prepare summoned 4 invisible ArmorStands on places where the command shall run and tag them (tag is optional for secure executing - and distinguishing the targets for multicommand uses in one area - like one armor stand will summon zombie and another will summon skeleton)

Then all you need is to target ArmorStands with `/execute` as before:

```
/execute @e[x=100,y=64,z=100,r=30,type=ArmorStand] ~0 ~0 ~0 /summon Zombie ~0 ~1 ~0 {CustomName:Tough Zombie,CustomNameVisible:1,Health:100.0f}
```

This will summon one zombie on every prepared armorstand  with one command. However you need multiple commands to prepare it.

Also you can target already existing summoned entity, however you need other command for first zombie (basic `/summon` on coordinates or on mark) and then `execute+summon` command to multiply it:

```
/summon Zombie 100 64 100 {CustomName:Tough Zombie,CustomNameVisible:1,Health:100.0f}
/execute @e[x=100,y=64,z=100,r=10,type=Zombie] ~0 ~0 ~0 /summon Zombie ~0 ~1 ~0 {CustomName:Tough Zombie,CustomNameVisible:1,Health:100.0f}
```

Those two commands will summon two zombies on same spot. Also you can put second command on redstone clock, executing it more times, so there will be more Zombies (but be sure to not spawn them fast, they can multiply exponentially and lag/crash the server!)

Also you can use scoreboards for the last thing, by tagging entities and adding them score for every command you do on them (for that you need chain commandblock that will operate the scoreboard) and then run command dependant on scoreboard score, as described [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Target_selector_arguments).

---

Hopefully this can help you to get what you need. And basically it answers possibilities to do this thing with only one command - with some prepared/basic situations, it is possible.

PS: Since 1.9 version, you can use chained commandblocks with ease, therefore it is really easy to use multiple commands that will execute just after each other, just by pressing one initial button. They are compact and can fulfill multiple tasks really easy.

Answer (score 0):

In the snapshots of 1.10 you can clone entities with the structure block

Comment: Can you explain?

Comment: @HarounMohamed-Fakier It takes area you mark and copies it somewhere else, blocks, entities, everything. However setup is not trivial, probably needs the marking done by hand, so it would be useful in really special occasions, I think. And it is not released yet, so it still can change.

Answer (score -1):

If you're trying this with people, it's impossible to do unless you're on a certain mod, such as the clone mod, and what you do on that mod is you kill yourself or the person you want to clone and it somehow clones itself as what I've heard of.

1. If you're doing this with mobs, it's possible unlike people. What you need to do is type in the chat or command block you're using is `/summon`. It should list animals/mobs in the chat, but in the command block it won't.
2. Type in the animal/mob you want such as "spider" or "villager".
3. You can also give your mob a nametag. If you do want to, you'll have to type its name obviously. Here are some interesting names:

   - Toast. What it does is makes it a different type, unlike the normal ones. It makes it black and white (not the normal black and white one.)
   - Do you wish to ride a horse upside down? Well, look no further. All you have to do is type in "Dinnerbone." It makes any mob or animal upside down, and voila, you can officially ride a horse upside down.
   - Do you wish to have a rainbow sheep? Well, just type the name, "jebb_" in. What it does is makes your sheep turn rainbow.
   - You know how vindicators only kill you or your friends? Well, you can make it kill *anything.* Just name it Johnny and it will kill anything instead of it just targeting you and your friends.

If this one doesn't work, well I'm sorry. I've only heard of it. That's all the advice I can give you. Have a great day!

Comment: I'm afraid that this only works on Bedrock Edition, this question is for Java Edition, as shown in this question's tags.

Answer (score -1):

There is a way to copy entities in minecraft using the structure block and when u want to load that specific block and entitie u can use a jigsaw block

Comment: Okay... if there is could you explain how to do so?